# DotNetNuke Module, change settings page from code behind

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Might seem like a bit of weird one but can anyone tell if it's possible to change which user control is loaded in the settings pop up, when the settings button for a module is clicked, from the code behind?

I'm sure this must be possible somehow, I've just not found it yet.

Comment: So are you trying to have different controls each time in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Hrmmm I'm not sure if could do that or not, but what you could possibly do, is in your settings control, just load whatever ASCX files you want loaded with your own logic there?

That being said, because of the way the settings base classes work, I am not sure how you might go about that.

Comment: Have tried adding the ascx as a control to the regualr settings page and have set the LoadSettings() and UpdateSettings() overrides on the regular setting page to reference the appropriate functions with in the code behind of the target settings. The html for the page loads and the code behind executes but because the functions are called from regular settings page namespace the code behind can't find any of the web controls on the page when it loads.

Comment: The alternative is I add a function to the class to create all the controls on the fly and don't even bother adding it as a control. But that seems like a bit pain.